# StackOverflowException in System.dll

Tags: c#, system, stack-overflow

So here i have a problem with my C# code..
It's repeating a thread for accepting new connections
But it gets StackOverflowException in System.dll after some minutes

Here is my code

```
void DoReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    var client = (TCPClient)args.UserToken;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    if (!client.socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        DoReceive(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling DoReceieve recursively, which leads to an SOE. This would be obvious from the stacktrace in your exception, and if you debugged. =)

Comment: And how can i prevent this thing? :S

Comment: How about using a while-loop and a limit on retries? That's more common than retrying for all eternity, recursively. =)

Comment: Can you be more specific about this? Like some code written? :P

Comment: [Someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15386611/64976) has already saved you the trouble of researching it yourself. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endless recursion leads to [`StackOverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx). Consider changing you code:

```
void DoReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    var client = (TCPClient)args.UserToken;        
    while (!client.socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now trying your solution :) I will tell here is it's working :) Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It must work:) I would also provide some timeout, or limited times of ReceiveAsync attempts to prevent endless cycle in case nothing is sent by the socket. But it depends on your logic of course.

Comment: Well everything good but after sometime the function stops and i need to restart the server... Any solutions?

Comment: Well, I can guess the method hangs only if the `ReceiveAsync` always returns `false`;)

Answer (score 1):

`DoReceive` called repeatedly if !client.socket.ReceiveAsync(args) then if this result not changed will raise StackOverflowException

the same Idea that `Olexander` give

```
void DoReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
 {   
    var client = (TCPClient)args.UserToken;        
    while (!client.socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
     {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
}
```

Comment: How can i prevent SOE? I need to make another if function in this?

Answer (score 0):

DoReceive is being called recursively every time ReceiveAsync returns false. It looks like ReceiveAsync is returning false more often than not, causing your program to run out of memory.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)

[StackOverflowException] "is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls"

---

You could set a static variable to keep a count of retries and quit after you reach a limit.